# React JS - Transform a static pagination to dynamic from JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a ReactJS code below made for a SO user [Piotr Berebecki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4186037/piotr-berebecki). The code is working succefully It is a handle pagination returning items from an array. I want to do the same thing but returning data from JSON DB How can I do? How can I solve it? Thank you. [Here is the app in the CodePen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Here is My DB Json. I want only return the images (named as 'fotos'). It will replace the 'todos' in the array in the second code below
. Note: It must be made by Axios.

```
{
"interiores": [
  {     
    "nome": "house 1",
    "descricao": "This is the description of the house 1",
    "fotos": [      
      "int_02", "int_02", "int_02", "int_02", "int_02"      
    ]
  }  
 ]
}
```

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Todo extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {      
      todos: ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k'],
      currentPage: 1,
      todosPerPage: 3     
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(event) {
    this.setState({
      currentPage: Number(event.target.id)
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { todos, currentPage, todosPerPage } = this.state;

    // Logic for displaying todos
    const indexOfLastTodo = currentPage * todosPerPage;
    const indexOfFirstTodo = indexOfLastTodo - todosPerPage;
    const currentTodos = todos.slice(indexOfFirstTodo, indexOfLastTodo);

    const renderTodos = currentTodos.map((todo, index) => {
      return <li key={index}>{todo}</li>;
    });

    // Logic for displaying page numbers
    const pageNumbers = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(todos.length / todosPerPage); i++) {
      pageNumbers.push(i);
    }

    const renderPageNumbers = pageNumbers.map(number => {
      return (
        <li
          key={number}
          id={number}
          onClick={this.handleClick}
        >
          {number}
        </li>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {renderTodos}
        </ul>
        <ul id="page-numbers">
          {renderPageNumbers}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Todo;
```

Comment: Are you asking how to make a call to the database or how to handle the data that you've already extracted from the database?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that I use axios to do it

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're asking how to handle the data once you've already made the call, this is how I think you should do it using componentDidMount I haven't tested it yet, but should give you a good starting point.

```
{
"interiores": [
  {     
    "nome": "house 1",
    "descricao": "This is the description of the house 1",
    "fotos": [      
      "int_02", "int_02", "int_02", "int_02", "int_02"      
    ]
  }  
 ]
}
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Todo extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {      
      todos: ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k'],
      currentPage: 1,
      todosPerPage: 3 ,
      fotos: '',
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(event) {
    this.setState({
      currentPage: Number(event.target.id)
    });
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
      //make call to database and set the db data to your state.
      const dbData = axios.get('http://yourapi.com/todods')
    .then(function (response) {
      this.setState({fotos: response.data.interiores[0].fotos})
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log('error:', error);
    });   
  }
  render() {
    const { todos, currentPage, todosPerPage } = this.state;

    // Logic for displaying todos
    const indexOfLastTodo = currentPage * todosPerPage;
    const indexOfFirstTodo = indexOfLastTodo - todosPerPage;
    const currentTodos = todos.slice(indexOfFirstTodo, indexOfLastTodo);

    const renderTodos = currentTodos.map((todo, index) => {
      return <li key={index}>{todo}</li>;
    });

    // Logic for displaying page numbers
    const pageNumbers = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(todos.length / todosPerPage); i++) {
      pageNumbers.push(i);
    }

    const renderPageNumbers = pageNumbers.map(number => {
      return (
        <li
          key={number}
          id={number}
          onClick={this.handleClick}
        >
          {number}
        </li>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {this.state.fotos? this.state.fotos : 'nothing to display' }
        </ul>
        <ul id="page-numbers">
          {renderPageNumbers}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Todo;
```

Comment: The 'interiores' from dbjson must replace the 'todo' array by using axios cathed from a json's url. 

Like that: componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(URL_INTERIORES)
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({ interiores: res.data })
      })
}

Comment: Note that the db 'interiores' object structure is a bit different from the 'todos' array.

Comment: Yes, you simply change to the proper path to your data. Made that change.

Comment: Also note that you probably should move your axios calls to a seperate file and import it whenever you need it.

Comment: The key of problem is a difficulty to handle the  db.json object comparing with the static array. it is a beginer issue

Comment: Atlante Avila - where I call the 'dbData' variable?

Comment: You can just ignore that. You will set the fotos array in the state and just go on to use it in your component from there.